# Will running the fans at maximum rpm all the time hurt the computer?

Tags: hardware, cooling

I installed Macs Fan Control and I like to make both fans in my mac work at top RPM available all the time. The sound does not annoy me at all and I really like that the computer runs cooler.

Will this hurt the computer in any way?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you mean exactly.

It will most likely mean that the fan itself will have a shorter lifetime before it fails. How much shorter is very hard to say - it might not mean much in practice.

The rest of the computer will definitely not be hurt by the fan running faster than usually.